# How to get a list of nuget packages installed via MSBuild macro?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

From following question [How do I list all installed NuGet packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363960/how-do-i-list-all-installed-nuget-packages)

I need to get a list of nuget packages from MSBuild itself.

What I try to do:

```
<Target Name="test" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences">
        <ItemGroup>
  <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"/>
</ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="Files @(BuildOutputInPackage -> '%(identity)', ', ')" Importance="high"/>

</Target>
```

Above code return all references whether its nuget or project references dlls. How exactly to return a list of nuget package that currently project *.csproj used?

Format i.e:   `packageid:Portable.BouncyCastle version = "1.9.0"`

I use old classic non-sdk csproj template and .NET 4.8 and `<PackageReference> not packages.config files.`

Its very bad to read *.csproj and do regex to get a list of <packageReferences. Maybe there's a recommended MSBuild macro to do this like code shown above <Target....

Comment: Does this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58557684/17296043 ) can help you?

Comment: I tested solution in that answer. It didn't work. I also try to do `Target Name="PrintPackageReferences" AfterTargets="ResolvePackageDependencies"` But nothing work. Looks like or maybe that solution is for sdk project style. not classic csproj that I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very thankful to [Jonathan Dodds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73058730/19572650) for his answer above. I combined some approach with his `@(PackageReference)` idea to get a version of currently referenced nuget package in old classic csproj template. Because a referenced version will not work with `@(PackageReference) only`. Also dotnet list not worked well in old classic csproj template (non-sdk).

**A code below do following:**

(Note this approach is not 100% organic, MSBuild should provide a simple target for that):

1. Get all references that maybe be nuget or non-nuget (DLLs, etc).
2. Get only references that included inside `@(PackageReference)`. [Jonathan Doods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73058730/19572650) approach above.
3. Get **.nuspec file** for that package to know exactly what version current *.csproj referenced.
4. Create a new nuspec file for current project. with a list of dependencies.
5. You can then call `nuget.exe pack ProjectPath.csproj` a **ProjectName.nupkg** nuget will generated.

**Use this code inside Directory.Build.targets or within your .csproj file.**

```
    <Target Name="GenerateNuspecFile">
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- Get all references -->
        <MyReference Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="%(extension) == '.dll'">
            <FirstDir>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent(%(RelativeDir)))</FirstDir>
            <LibDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(%(MyReference.FirstDir)))</LibDir>
            <SecondDir>$(FirstDir)</SecondDir>
            <SecondDir Condition="$(LibDir) != 'lib'">$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent(%(MyReference.FirstDir)))</SecondDir>
            <VersionDir>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent(%(MyReference.SecondDir)))</VersionDir>
            <PackageDir>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetParent(%(MyReference.VersionDir)))</PackageDir>
            <PackageID>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(%(MyReference.PackageDir)))</PackageID>
            <NuspecFile>%(MyReference.VersionDir)\%(MyReference.PackageID).nuspec</NuspecFile>
        </MyReference>

        <!-- Get Non nuget references -->
        <ExcludedReference Condition="@(MyReference) != ''" Include="@(MyReference -> '%(PackageID)')" Exclude="@(PackageReference -> '%(identity)')"/>

        <!-- Get nuget references after exclude non-nuget references -->
        <MyPackage Condition="@(MyReference) != ''" Include="@(MyReference -> '%(PackageID)')" Exclude="@(ExcludedReference -> '%(identity)')"/>

        <!-- Read Nuspec File -->
        <NuspecContent Condition="@(NuspecFile) != ''" Include="%(MyPackage.NuspecFile)">
            <Content>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(fullpath)))</Content>
            <PackageIDRegex>&lt;id&gt;(.*?)&lt;/id&gt;</PackageIDRegex>
            <PackageID>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match('%(NuspecContent.Content)', '%(NuspecContent.PackageIDRegex)' ))</PackageID>
            <PackageID>$([System.String]::Copy('%(NuspecContent.PackageID)').Replace('&lt;id&gt;','').Replace('&lt;/id&gt;', '').Trim())</PackageID>

            <VersionRegex>&lt;version&gt;(.*?)&lt;/version&gt;</VersionRegex>
            <Version>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match('%(NuspecContent.Content)', '%(NuspecContent.VersionRegex)' ))</Version>
            <Version>$([System.String]::Copy('%(NuspecContent.Version)').Replace('&lt;version&gt;','').Replace('&lt;/version&gt;', '').Trim())</Version>
        </NuspecContent>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Generate Nuspec File with dependencies-->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <NewLine>%0d%0a</NewLine>
        <Space2>%20%20</Space2>
        <Space4>$(Space2)$(Space2)</Space4>
        <Space6>$(Space4)$(Space2)</Space6>
        <HasDependencies>false</HasDependencies>
        <HasDependencies Condition="@(MyPackage) != ''">true</HasDependencies>

        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)&lt;package &gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space2)&lt;metadata&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;id&gt;$id$&lt;/id&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;version&gt;$version$&lt;/version&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;title&gt;$title$&lt;/title&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;authors&gt;$author$&lt;/authors&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;owners&gt;$author$&lt;/owners&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;requireLicenseAcceptance&gt;false&lt;/requireLicenseAcceptance&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;licenseUrl&gt;https://Your Company.com&lt;/licenseUrl&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;icon&gt;PackageIcon.png&lt;/icon&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;projectUrl&gt;http://Your Company.com&lt;/projectUrl&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;description&gt;$description$&lt;/description&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;releaseNotes&gt;$description$&lt;/releaseNotes&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;copyright&gt;$copyright$&lt;/copyright&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;tags&gt;$title$ Your Company Your Company.com&lt;/tags&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>

        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;dependencies&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec Condition="$(HasDependencies)">$(Nuspec)$(Space6)&lt;group targetFramework=&quot;.NETFramework4.8&quot;&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec Condition="$(HasDependencies)">$(Nuspec)@(NuspecContent -> '$(Space6)&lt;dependency id=&quot;%(PackageID)&quot; version=&quot;%(Version)&quot;/&gt;', '$(NewLine)')$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec Condition="$(HasDependencies)">$(Nuspec)$(Space6)&lt;/group&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;/dependencies&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>

        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space2)&lt;/metadata&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space2)&lt;files&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space4)&lt;file src="..\**\PackageIcon.png"/&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)$(Space2)&lt;/files&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
        <Nuspec>$(Nuspec)&lt;/package&gt;$(NewLine)</Nuspec>
    </PropertyGroup>        
    <WriteLinesToFile Lines="$(Nuspec)" File="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(MSBuildProjectName).nuspec" Overwrite="true"/>
</Target>
```

The generated `.nuspec` file will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl>https://company.com</licenseUrl>
    <icon>PackageIcon.png</icon>
    <projectUrl>http://company.com</projectUrl>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>$description$</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>$title$ company company.com</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Company.Globals" version="2022.7.19"/>
      <dependency id="Portable.BouncyCastle" version="1.9.0"/>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\**\PackageIcon.png"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Its really to hard to achieve anything with MSBuild. Maybe you can create a console app for that and just call console app directly with `<Exec Command =""/>`. But current approach is friendly with MSBuild. Its not 100% organic approach. MSBuild should provide us a target to get a referenced nuget packages with its referenced version.

Answer (score 1):

`ReferenceCopyLocalPaths` is only "Paths to files that should be copied to the local directory." It is not all resolved references.

Yes, don't regex the project file. There is no need. `PackageReference` is an ItemGroup.

```
<Target Name="DisplayPackageReference">
    <Message Text="@(PackageReference ->'packageid:%(identity) version = &quot;%(version)&quot;', '%0d%0a')" />
</Target>
```

But note that `PackageReference` is what the project is asking for and the version can be floating, e.g `Version="3.6.*"`. `PackageReference` won't give you the package version that the package reference was resolved to.

If you need to know the specific version used, then you may need to install `dotnet`, use an `exec` task to run `dotnet list "$(MSBuildProjectFile)" package`, and parse the command's output.

Comment: Thank you much dear I use `@(PackageReference) ` you provided with `.nuspec` file that project referenced to get package id with referenced version. I wish there's a more simple approach. But its good to combine things together :)